# Mocha hooks suddenly not executing (at all, in any test)

Tags: testing, express, mocha.js

I was plugging along with Mocha testing an API in Express. Things were working as expected, but as of a few hours ago, suddenly no tests would run. I've made no changes since things were working, except in the tests themselves, so I'm not sure what the deal is. I even tried scrapping everything so now all I'm trying to get running is this:

```
describe('make a test run', function(){

  console.log('entered test');

  before( function(){ 
    console.log('before'); 
  });

  it('test 1', function(){ 
    console.log('1'); 
  });
  it('test 2', function(){
   console.log('2'); 
  });
  it('test 2', function(){ 
    console.log('2'); 
  });

  after( function(){ 
    console.log('after'); 
  });

  console.log('ran through test');

});
```

It'll print "entered test" and "ran through test," but nothing in between. What in the world have I got wrong?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem you are reporting. I took the code above, cut and pasted it into a file called `test.js` and ran `mocha` at the command line. I get output from all the `console` statements and everything else Mocha would report including that 3 tests passed. Are you sure you are not running Mocha with an option that makes it skip all your tests (e.g. `--grep asdfasd`, which would match none of your tests)? Check your `mocha.opts` too if you created one.

Comment: Coming back to this a little late- thanks for the reply! I can't remember exactly what the issue ended up being, but I think it was indeed an options problem.